# Number To Arabic Words

Tags: c#, .net

I need to convert a Number to Arabic Word. Does anyone have a code sample or library for that in C#,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210586

This converts to english, so change the code to convert to arabic.

If you need actual words back in arabic see this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Number_to_Arabic_text.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Arabic is different from English in a sense that counting a feminine noun is different than counting a masculine noun. Arabic language uses [duals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_%28grammatical_number%29); which affects counting as well.  Translating an English "number to words" algorithm would give you a head start but you need to take care of the grammatical differences.

LibStation.com has a Numbers-in-Words .NET libary that supports Arabic. They have a demo application that you can download and fiddle around with. Check out their [website](http://libstation.com/products/numbers-in-words/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem, and after days of searching the internet, I finally came to a very simple, customizable, and easy to learn solution, you can find it at the following [link](http://asmaqureshi.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-convert-numbers-to-arabic-word.html)

Answer (score -1):

There is now an api for that
https://rapidapi.com/postscripter/api/tafqit
same functionality the website tafqit.com is based on